# ASP.NET WebApi + Autofac not finding ApiControllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to get Autofac to work with WebApi. I have my ApiControllers in a separate project from the main web project.

InventorySystem.Web.UI
InventorySystem.Web.Api.Controllers

Whenever i try to browse to an api route i get the response:

```
<Exception xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ExceptionType>System.ArgumentNullException</ExceptionType>
    <Message>Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value</Message>
    <StackTrace>
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext.set_Controller(IHttpController value)
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerFactory.CreateInstance(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerFactory.CreateController(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, String controllerName)
at Autofac.Integration.WebApi.AutofacControllerFactory.CreateController(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, String controllerName)
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsyncInternal(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    </StackTrace>
</Exception>
```

When i step through the Autofac code I see that my controller has been registered, but the AutofacControllerActivator.Create() returns null. Specifically the line
    return (ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(scope, controllerType) as IHttpController);

The autofac code:
string binDirectory = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "bin");

```
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.ConfigureWebApi(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).PropertiesAutowired();
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.LoadFile(Path.Combine(binDirectory, "InventorySystem.Web.Api.dll"))).PropertiesAutowired();
        builder.RegisterFilterProvider();            

        var container = builder.Build();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.ServiceResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container));
```

Am i missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Is the assembly location you are providing to RegisterAPIControllers definitely correct? I got the same error when I made a mistake with my assembly name.

Comment: @Gavin yes, because my apicontroller does get registerred. It's just the resolving which seems to fail.

Answer (score 2):

The RegisterApiControllers registration extension looks for types that implement the `IHttpController` interface and have a name that ends with "Controller". Do your controller class names have a suffix of "Controller"?

Comment: Yes, it implements IHttpController eventually and the name also ends with Controller.
Also, if i put my api controller in the main project it works fine.
I'll try to create a test project to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I'm also not sure if
lifetimeScope.ResolveOptional(controllerType) returns null
or the cast to IHttpController. Any way I could check this easily?

Comment: (we work at the same place, thus I have access to the code): builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(InventorySystem.Web.Api.Controllers.InventoryController).Assembly).PropertiesAutowired(); fixed the issue, however we would like to be able to use Assembly.Load so we can switch between implementations and what not. Please advice why we see this behavior. (And: Thanks for the Autofac integration module! We love Autofac and all that integrates well with it)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to give a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423992/autofac-with-mvc4-controller-does-not-have-a-default-constructor), where the *other* assembly is picked up starting from one of the references API Controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you forgetting to register constructor dependencies for your Api controllers with the build container?

HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/bin") is another good way to get the path to a file in the bin directory.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help.

Answer (score -1):

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();   
builder.Update(container);
 var webApiResolver = new Autofac.Integration.WebApi.AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = webApiResolver;
```