# Autofac with MVC4: controller does not have a default constructor

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-4, autofac

I've been working with Autofac in MVC3 and love it. Now I am trying to implement it with MVC4.

I installed the pre-release versions of Autofac MVC4 and Autofac WebApi through the Package Manager Console (Install-Package Autofac.Mvc4 -Pre and Install-Package Autofac.WebApi -Pre)

I adjusted my IoC container as following:

```
    private static void SetAutofacContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerHttpRequest().InstancePerApiRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<DatabaseFactory>().As<IDatabaseFactory>().InstancePerHttpRequest().InstancePerApiRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<RepositoryWrapper>().As<RepositoryWrapper>().InstancePerHttpRequest().InstancePerApiRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<ServiceWrapper>().As<ServiceWrapper>().InstancePerHttpRequest().InstancePerApiRequest();

        // Repositories
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(UserRepository).Assembly).Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository")).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerHttpRequest().InstancePerApiRequest();

        // Services
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(UserService).Assembly).Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service")).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerHttpRequest().InstancePerApiRequest();

        IContainer container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

    }
```

When I run the application (by accessing the API controller) I get the exception:
"**Controllers.UserController' does not have a default constructor**"

The controller looks like this:

```
namespace Controllers
{
[Authorize]
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    private ServiceWrapper _services;

    public UserController(ServiceWrapper services)
    {
        _services = services;
    }

    // GET api/user/{userrequest}
    public IQueryable<User> Get(UserRequest request)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          '...
        }  
    } 
}
```

Am I missing something? Did I not set it up right? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update**

My API controller are within a separate project in the same solution. If I place the API controller in my main MVC project, it works. Could someone please enlighten me on how to get Autofac to register the API controllers in my API project?

Comment: could you show your usercontroller class?

Comment: From where do you call the `SetAutofacContainer` method?

Comment: In Application_Start() in Global.asax

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With the `RegisterApiControllers` method you tell Autofac where (in which assembly) it should look for your `ApiControllers`

So the following call:

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Registers the `ApiControllers` from the current assembly (project).

If you have `ApiController`s also in a different project you need to use it like this:

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(UserController).Assembly);
```

Which means: register **all** the `ApiController` form the assembly (project) where the `UserController` lives. So you only need one `RegisterApiControllers` per assembly even if you have multiple `ApiController` in an assembly (project).

Comment: You mean `RegisterControllers`? There doesn't seem to be `RegisterApiControllers` method.

Comment: @drozzy there is two methods `RegisterControllers` for the MVC controllers and `RegisterApiController` for the web.api controllers. The `RegisterApiController` only available if you use the Autofac.WebAPi extension.

Comment: @nemesv D'oh, thanks! Even though I did have to call both `RegisterControllers` and `RegisterApiControllers`. Weird.

Comment: @nemesv do you know if there is any issue doing:

builder.RegisterControllers(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            builder.RegisterApiControllers(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

At the same time?